# Counting CNN layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

i created a CNN for a project i am involved with and i need to present it. The issue is, I am not sure about how to count the layers.

Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), input_shape = (40,40,2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))


model.add(Dense(1600))
model.add(Reshape((40,40)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='MSE',
             optimizer='SGD',
             metrics=['MAE'])
```

len(model.layers) returned 12 :

So i used 1 input 10 hidden 1 output layers,

or

i need to count them as a group and say 1 input 2 hidden 1 output?

Comment: Just write 12 layers, no need to talk about input or hidden layers, those concepts are kind of obosolete

Comment: Oh i see, thank you :)

Comment: Naming convention omits input layer in the network, thus your architecture can have 11 layers. To know more see http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/

Comment: In common practice, we only count convolutional layers and dense layers. For example, the VGG-16 is described as network with 16 **weight layers** in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1556). Your network is a 4-layer network (2 conv + 2 fc).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When calculating the depth of a CNN network, we only consider the layers that have tunable/trainable weights/parameters. In CNN only Convolutional Layers and Fully Connected Layers will have trainable parameters. If you want to label layers consider only Convolutional, Full Connected and Output layers (Conv2D and Dense).
Max Pooling Layers are generally take together with Convolutional Layers as one layer.

Comment: Rigorously, there are a few trainable parameters in batchnorm layers,  but we do not count bn layers either :)

Comment: Yeah that correct even though we have trainable gamma and beta parameters in Batch Normalization we don't consider that as a layer. It's a normalization technique for activation values .